# how to set state in react componentDidMount with method?

Tags: reactjs

code is like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState(({getPublicTodosLength}, props) => ({
      getPublicTodosLength: () => this.getPublicTodosLengthForPagination() // no returned value
    }));
  }
  getPublicTodosLengthForPagination = async () => { // get publicTodos length since we cannot get it declared on createPaginationContainer
        const getPublicTodosLengthQueryText = `
          query TodoListHomeQuery {# filename+Query
            viewer {
              publicTodos {
                edges {
                  node {
                    id
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }`
    const getPublicTodosLengthQuery = { text: getPublicTodosLengthQueryText }
    const  result = await this.props.relay.environment._network.fetch(getPublicTodosLengthQuery, {})
    return result.data.viewer.publicTodos.edges.length; 
  }
```

getPublicTodosLengthForPagination is not invoked and the returned value is not assigned.Also, When i invoke it right away e.g. without () => it's assigned value is a promise? I am expecting int/number, the return value of edges.length. help?

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: @stybl no errors, when i invoke it right away e.g. without () => it's assigned to a promise?

Answer (score 0):

The returned value is not assigned because you are not invoking the function rather assigning it.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState(({getPublicTodosLength}, props) => ({
      getPublicTodosLength: this.getPublicTodosLengthForPagination() 
    }));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're setting state like that, maybe you could help explain what you're doing. In the meantime shouldn't it be written like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      getPublicTodosLength: await this.getPublicTodosLengthForPagination() // no returned value
    });
  }

  getPublicTodosLengthForPagination = async () => { // get publicTodos length since we cannot get it declared on createPaginationContainer
        const getPublicTodosLengthQueryText = `
          query TodoListHomeQuery {# filename+Query
            viewer {
              publicTodos {
                edges {
                  node {
                    id
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }`
    const getPublicTodosLengthQuery = { text: getPublicTodosLengthQueryText }
    const  result = await this.props.relay.environment._network.fetch(getPublicTodosLengthQuery, {})
    return result.data.viewer.publicTodos.edges.length; 
  }
```